How to convert $y^2 = x^3 +7$ over $F_p$ to $y^2 = x^3 + 12$ over $F_p$
p = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663
Fp = GF(p)
E07 = EllipticCurve(Fp, [0, 7])
E12= EllipticCurve(Fp, [0,12])
Then, E12.order() == E07.order() is true.

How should I map the public key point $E07(F_p)$ to $E12(F_p)$? I want to know the specific coordinate conversion.

Do you need the mapping $f$ from $E_{07}$ to $E_{12}$ to be an isomorphism, that is be such that $f(P+Q)=f(P)+f(Q)$? Note: when first seeing the question, I did not see an efficiently computable solution even if this isomorphism condition was waved. But if we remove "efficiently computable", an answer is easy: find generators $G_{07}\in E_{07}$ and $G_{12}\in E_{12}$, and map $[k]G_{07}$ to $[k]G_{12}$ for an isomorphism.

@fgrieu they meant mapping $(x,y) \to (x',y')$ so that one doesn't need to find dlogs to maps. This is performed over the equations, however, this is, high probably a HW!

https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/weierstrass_morphism.html Can you do the rest?

@kelalaka: I did not know this was possible!

Assume $v$ is such that $v^6=12/7$ in the field $\mathbb F_p$. It follows that if $y^2=x^3+7$ in that field, then $x'=v^2\,x$ and $y'=v^3\,y$ are such that ${y'}^2={x'}^3+12$. Thus $f$ with $f((x,y))=(v^2\,x,v^3\,y)$ is a bijective mapping between the non-identity points of the two curves $E_{07}$ and $E_{12}$. When we further map the identity points, this is a group isomorphism; that is $f(P+Q)=f(P)+f(Q)$ where the left (resp. right) $+$ stands for point addition in $E_{07}$ (resp. $E_{12}$).
This is actually a special case of the isomorphism between Weierstrass models of elliptic curves pointed by @kelalaka in comment, with $u=1/v$, $r=s=t=0$, $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=0$, $a'_1=a'_2=a'_3=a'_4=0$.
It's left as an exercise to the reader to find $v$. The smallest positive $v$ has $v\bmod10^3=663$.

The existence of this isomorphism proves that the difficulty of attacking secp256k1 is not impaired by the choice of the small constant $7$, rather than an other constant yielding the same group order.
